# Primefaces fileupload how to stop running upload

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Is it possible to stop a running upload for one or several files using  javascript?

Comment: what does mean a "running" upload ? Interrupt it ? in which condition ?

Comment: E. g. a upload is started with 10 files...the user clicks a button when file 5 is uploaded...the remaining files will not be uploaded.